# How do I insert double quote (") inside an expression of MsgBox?

Tags: excel, msgbox, vba

I have this code having multiple use of MsgBox function. So there are few words which I want to keep it in Double Quotes ("") viz, any Brand's name and something. I'm getting an error when I simply enter the double quotes...
I hope there's a way out...

Comment: `MsgBox "This how you ""do"" it"`

Comment: Another version - `MsgBox "This how you " & Chr(34) & "do" & Chr(34) & " it"`

Comment: Also, `MsgBox "This " & """" & "is" & """" & " how you do it"`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks. Actually I was using just one double quote, like, [MsgBox "There are "non-numeric" values here"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double quotes to *close* then *reopen* the string.

You can also use the msgbox function depending on waht all you have/want:

```
Sub fdsa()
    Dim i As String, j As Long
    i = "Cat "
    j = Cells(1, 1).Value * Cells(1, 2).Value
    MsgBox (i & j)  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub DontQuoteMe()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Hello World" & vbCrLf & """Hello World"""
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]